# Is there a reaction between ethanol and aluminum?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity, organometallic-compounds

Is there a potential reaction that would occur between ethanol and aluminum? If so, would it potentially create anything toxic?

Comment: Yes it is, it is an industrial way to prepare aluminiuum isopropoxide.

Comment: In what situation? Normally there's no significant reaction.

Comment: Mercury(II) chloride is a necessary condition for this synthesis to occur, because usual aluminum is covered by a thin waterproof and continuous protective layer of aluminum oxide (alumina). This layer prevents the metal aluminum to get in touch with any liquid. In the presence of dissolved mercury chloride, the layer is not continuous anymore. So aluminum can react with water, ethanol, or isopropanol, producing gaseous hydrogen and aluminum hydroxide (or ethoxide, or isopropoxide).

Comment: @Maurice, For rapid *synthesis*, a way of breaking the Al2O3 coating is needed (might Ga would work, too?), but for long-term *storage*, aluminum is attacked by the lower alcohols, as I've observed by using a container with (unanodized) Al top for storing isopropanol. After a year or so, the top was covered with a white crust and badly corroded. No Hg was involved in this inadvertent test!

Comment: Thank you for the information, Dr Pippik. I did not know about this extremely slow reaction. And of course, gallium works as well.

Answer (score 6):

The reaction of aluminum and ethanol forms [aluminum triethoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_triethoxide),  $\ce{ Al(OC2H5)3}$, but the reaction is fairly *slow at room temperature*, particularly if the aluminum is anodized. In the presence of any moisture it decomposes into aluminum hydroxide and ethanol.

The [Safety Data Sheet](https://www.alfa.com/content/msds/USA/41336.pdf) indicates that aluminum triethoxide is both flammable and can cause "severe skin burns and eye damage", but in atmospheric conditions it *likely decomposes as quickly as it forms*, so the main adverse effect will be the corrosion of the aluminum, covering it with a white crust of $\ce{Al2O3}$ (I've seen this happen to an aluminum lid on a container used for ethanol).

[UNH has posted a chart that shows that *anodized* aluminum *is* resistant to ethanol attack](http://www.camis.unh.edu/camis/services/chem_compatibility_table.html), but does not state at what temperature, so you may have to experiment to see if it suitable in your application.

BTW, many other alcohols react in a similar manner, such as isopropanol, which forms [aluminium isopropoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_isopropoxide) with aluminum.

Comment: I have seen the same:  the main adverse effect will be the corrosion of the aluminum, covering it with a white crust of Al2O3
A
l
2
O
3
 (I've seen this happen to an aluminum lid on a container used for ethanol).